# Triggering "click" event on a checkbox or radio button toggles the "checked" property after the event handler function finish

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox, radio-button

Strange behave on jquery click event over radioButton and checkbox

when a user click on a radio button, the property check is toggle first and then the event handler is run.

when the code trigger click event on those elements, first the event handler is running and then the check property is changing.

example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/j2bs01ez/3/

```
 <body >
  <input type="radio" id="test-checkbox" name="test" checked="true"/>
      <input type="radio" id="test-checkbox2" name="test"/>
  <span id="test-click">trigger click event</span>
 </body>

$(function(){


    $("#test-click").click(function(){

        $("#test-checkbox2").click();

    });

    $(document).on("click",'[name$="test"]',function () { 

        print();

    });
    var print=function(){
    alert( $('input[name$="test"]:checked').attr("id"));

    };
});
```

how can I avoid this problem and trigger the click after the property check is toggle?

Comment: This is really confusing? Firstly, the proper event would be `change`, not `click`, secondly, if you just want to toggle them when clicking something else, there are far easier ways ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j2bs01ez/4/

Comment: that one  soultion you can post it as an answer and if no one else will suggest a better answer I will accept it

Comment: Well, is that what you're trying to do, just toggle the radio buttons ?

Comment: It's a little more complicated, because there are more than 2 radio buttons.but I know the Id of the click radio , so I can check it first and then run the event. it similar to your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggling the radio boxes when you click another element should be as easy as

```js
$("#test-click").on('click', function() {
    $('[name$="test"]:not(:checked)').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="test-checkbox" name="test" checked="true" />
<input type="radio" id="test-checkbox2" name="test" /> 
<br /><br />
<span id="test-click">Click to toggle radios</span>
```

Comment: by the way I found this articale about the subject:http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1525-jquery-s-event-triggering-order-of-default-behavior-and-triggerhandler.htm

Answer (score 0):

One simple function to do this:

```
function checkNextRadioInGroup (group) {
    var group = ":radio[name='" + group + "']";
    var current = $(group + ":checked").index();
    var all = $(group).length - 1;
    if (current == all) {
        $(group + ":first").trigger("click");
    }
    else {
        $(group + ":checked").next().trigger("click");
    }
};
```

Then you can call it in your click-event like so:

```
$("#test-click").on("click", function(){
    checkNextRadioInGroup ("test");
});
```

This is just an example.

[Live here.](https://jsfiddle.net/j2bs01ez/5/)

Hope it helps.